# Storing additional values in a cookie PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

Long story short, I'm trying to exclude posts that have already been clicked from being included in a WordPress loop.

So I'm setting cookies based on post ID's when a user visits a post like this:

```
$post_id = the_ID();
setcookie('post-id', serialize($post_id), time()+3600);
```

But how do I then retrieve this cookie and add on another post ID to it so that I can have an array of post ID's stored in the cookie to exclude from the WordPress loop?

I've tried deserializing the data and then adding on to and setting the cookie again but I think I'm not getting the syntax right.

Any help would be much obliged.

**UPDATE**

Here's my loop reference:

```
$args = array (
       'post_type'              => 'post',
       'post_status'            => 'publish',
       'orderby'                => 'rand',
       'date_query'             => array( 'after' => $desktop_posts_after ), // Show posts after certain date
       'cat'                    => $cat_ID, // Show posts from same category as post
       'post__not_in'           => array($cookie_post_ids), // Hide current post from loop
       'posts_per_page'         => $desktop_posts, // Get number of posts to display for desktop

);
```

Note: you can see there are some variables in the loop from ACF, these are intentional and are working.  The important part is the `"post__not_in" => array($cookie_post_ids)` variable where I'm trying to feed the post ID's of posts stored in the cookies.

Comment: so show what you'd attempted. we don't write code for you, we (maybe) try help fix what you have written.

Comment: You are doing directly serialize of value.  You have to use first create a empty array after push a new value and serialize the value.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense @shashikant.  I'll explore that some more.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading about [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and storing this data inside of one:

```
<?php

session_start();

$posts = array_key_exists('post_ids', $_SESSION) ? (array) $_SESSION['post_ids'] : [];

$post_id = the_ID();

$posts[$post_id] = null;

$_SESSION['post_ids'] = $posts;
```

If you would like to store it in a cookie, you'll need to serialize an array of post IDs:

```
<?php

$post_id = the_ID();

$posts = array_key_exists('post-id', $_COOKIE) ? (string) $_COOKIE['post-id'] : [];

if (is_string($_COOKIE['post-id'])) {
    $posts = unserialize($posts);
}

$posts[$post_id] = null;

setcookie('post-id', serialize($posts), time() + 3600);
```

For both examples, after getting the $posts variable populated from either the session or the cookie, you can check if the user has visited the post by doing the following:

```
<?php

if (array_key_exists($post_id, $posts)) {
    echo 'User has already visited post ID ' . $post_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank.  I'm using the cookie method, and I see it stores a new cookie for each with the same name "post-id" and has a value associated with each.  How do I put all these values into an array so I can feed it into the WP loop?

Comment: No problem! $posts (in both examples) contains an array with each index being a post ID. Could you provide an example of the code where you'll be feeding the IDs into a loop? Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing!  I just updated my answer with the loop.

Comment: Thanks! If you are using the code from my answer, could you try changing your code to look like this: 'post__not_in' => array_keys($posts); That should do the trick!

Comment: Legend!  I'll give it a try.